# is it possible to run a different version of sql server trial once you've already run one?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, licensing

e.g. Have already installed trial version of SQL Server Enterprise Edition 2008 R2, is it now possible to switch to a trial version of the Developer edition?

Answer (score 2):

One would assume that you could since they are different SKUs.  If that doesn't work, you could buy the developer version for about $50.

Best bet would be to run the installer and see what happens.

Comment: I was about to make the same suggestion regarding Developer. I'm not even sure there is a trial version. But at $50 it is good to have a copy on a test box any way.